# Different between foo.prototyp.x = & foo.prototype = {x: }

Tags: javascript, prototype

I don't understand why fooA and fooB outcome different.

```
var foo = function(){}

fooA = new foo();

foo.prototype.x = 1;
foo.prototype = { y: 2, z: 3};

console.log(fooA.x, fooA.y, fooA.z);// 1, undefined, undefined

fooB = new foo();
console.log(fooB.x, fooB.y, fooB.z);// undefined, 2, 3
```

1. does foo.prototyp = {} override the method defined in front of it?
2. Why fooA is state in front of prototype.x, it inherit the result, but not y and z?

Comment: `Foo.prototype = {}` is actually re-defining what `Foo` is as an object, you're just caught in between an instance defined before and after the change. use `console.log(FooA); console.log(FooB);` to see the difference clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for that behavior is that you make `foo.prototype` point to a new object when using `foo.prototype = { y: 2, z: 3};`, and existing objects' prototypes don't change when the constructor's `prototype` property is set to a new value.

A line-by-line explanation of what happens:

**`var foo = function(){}`**

`foo.prototype` is initialized as an empty object (we shall call this object `A`).

**`fooA = new foo()`**

`fooA` is set to a new foo object, it has its prototype set to `foo.prototype` (`A`).

**`foo.prototype.x = 1`**

Because `fooA`'s prototype is the same object as `foo.prototype`, `fooA.x` becomes 1. In other words, `A` gets the property `x = 1`.

**`foo.prototype = { y: 2, z: 3};`**

We create a new object that has the properties `y = 2` and `z = 3`. We shall call this object `B`. `foo.prototype` is set to the new object.

**`console.log(fooA.x, fooA.y, fooA.z);`**

`fooA`'s prototype is still `A`, which only has the `x = 1` property.

**`fooB = new foo();`**

We create a new foo object whose prototype is `B`.

**`console.log(fooB.x, fooB.y, fooB.z);`**

`fooB`'s prototype is `B`, which has the properties `y = 2` and `z = 3`, but not the property `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
var foo = function(){}

fooA = new foo();

foo.prototype.x = 1;
console.log(fooA.__proto__) // {x:1}

foo.prototype = { y: 2, z: 3};
console.log(fooA.__proto__) // still {x:1}
```

An object's prototype is assigned at creation time (when calling `new`) and doesn't change afterwards.
See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
F.prototype = { ... };
```

replaces the `prototype` object of constructor `F`. The old `prototype` object is replaced by a new `prototype` object.

Instances of `F`

```
var f = new F();
```

have an implicit **prototype link** which refers to the `prototype` object of constructor `F`. However, this reference is established during the initialization of the instance.

For example

```
var f1 = new F();
F.prototype = { ... };
var f2 = new F();
```

Here, the prototype link of `f1` refers to the old `prototype` object, while the prototype link of `f2` refers to the new `prototype` object.

Notice that even though the `F.prototype` object has been replaced, the old `prototype` object will **continue to exist** as long as there is at least one instance of `F` whose prototype link refers to it.